# How to use generated classed from CXF/SoapUI in a Grails app?

Tags: tomcat, grails, cxf

I've created classes from the WSDL via SoapUI, but when deploying to a test (works on my local machine) Tomcat server, I am getting the following the stacktrace

What am I missing here? Do I have to do anything different to get the binding to work on  a remote server?

```
InputSource must have a ByteStream or CharacterStream

at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:983)

at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:217)

... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

What I need is to have these generated class pointing to embedded WSDL files in the app. Figured out that I need to modify each generated service class to load the appropriate wsdlLocation from the jar.